# DCOM library missing if install VxWorks 6.9 on Linux host instead of Windows

Tags: linux, vxworks, dcom

I'm moving an existing `VxWorks 6.9` build system from `Windows` to `RedHat Linux`.  In theory this should be easy but it seems that if I install VxWorks 6.9, **from the same CD**, on Linux then the `dcom-2.3` library (and a couple of others) are **not** installed - installing from the same CD on Windows **does** install them.

Anyone know what I am?  This is a *cross-compiler* environment for an embedded system so I can't see any reason that the installed libraries should be different between the two host systems.

Comment: I don't the answer but a workaround is to install on Windows, recursive-`scp` to your Linux system the dcom and opc components and then recursive `chown` and `chmod` to match the permissions of the other components.

Comment: There is no the Linux equivalent of dcom-2.3\host\x86-win32\bin\widl.exe.

Comment: @JaeMannYeh Thanks for that info.  Would I be correct that the `widl` executable is only required to produce Windows components to work with the VxWorks image so if I was not producing the Windows stuff, I would not need `widl`?  Is there an official VxWorks doc. that describes what `widl` does?

Comment: wr_dcom_vxworks_6_users_guide_2.3.pdf mentions only Microsoft COM documents. I only know a little about DCOM.

Comment: @JaeMannYeh It does look like the Windows executables are simply not used unless you are building a Windows "plugin".  What I did was simply the copy the missing components from a Windows install, place them in the correct place in the Linux enviroment, set permissions and voila - all worked (subject to the normal Windows/Linux command file/shell script and CR/CRLF fun).